# Connecting java with sql. error

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

```
package pokemon;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;


public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    getConnection();

}
public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception{
    try{
        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306:Pokedex";
        String username = "test";
        String password = "password";
        Class.forName(driver);

        Connection conn =      DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);  
        System.out.println("Connected");
        return conn;            
    } catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}


    return null;
}
}
```

I get the error

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException:
>   Cannot load connection class because of underlying exception:
>   'java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "3306:Pokedex"'.

I'm simply trying to see if I'm connected to the database so that I can enter data in my tables.

Comment: Your url is incorrect. It should be `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Pokedex`

Answer (score 1):

You are write wrong url. plz Replace it with this line

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Pokedex";
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html

Answer (score 1):

Your database URL is incorrect. It needs to be

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Pokedex
```

You would use a JDBC connection pool whenever possible unless you have a very basic application.

Comment: Thank you very much!! That did indeed fix it.